# No instance of constructor when trying to make a function for chrono in C++

Tags: c++, function, auto, c++-chrono

I need to calculate the runtime of my algorithms. I am using the following structure to do this:

```
auto start = std::chrono::stedy_clock::now();
//code
auto end = std::chrono::stedy_clock::now();
auto diff = end - start;
std::cout << std::chrono::duration <double, std::milli> (diff).count() << " ms" << endl;
```

However, since I have multiple algorithms I need to test I decided to make the following functions:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> time_now()
{
    return std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}

void print_time(std::ostream& out, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock differnce)
{
    out << std::chrono::duration <double, std::micro> (differnce).count() << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following error from vscode for my print function:

```
no instance of constructor "std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>::duration [with _Rep=double, _Period=std::micro]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock)
```

Any idea why I have this problem and how I can solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: please place the code actually calling the `print_time` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the wrong type to your `print_time` function.  The function is being declared, but when you pass your duration into it, the compiler is trying to convert a `duration` into a `clock` which doesn't make sense, which is why you're getting that constructor message.

Some of the time types are:

- `clock(s)` various things we can query for specific `time_points` with `now()`
- `time_points` represents a specific instant in time.
- `duration` a difference between `time_points`

It should be this:

```
void print_time(std::ostream& out,
  std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro> delta)
{
    out << delta.count() << std::endl;
}
```